# How do you adjust the height and borderRadius of a BottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: material-design, flutter, bottom-sheet

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but my BottomSheet only takes up the bottom half the screen, even though the widgets in it take up more space. So now there is scrolling behavior inside the BottomSheet. I'd like to be able to increase the BottomSheet so that the user doesn't have to scroll as much.

I also want to add a borderRadius to the top of my BottomSheet, so that it looks more "modal"-y or "tab"-like.

Code:

```
void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<Null>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return _bottomSheetScreen; // defined earlier on
      },
    );
}
```

I've tried:

```
showModalBottomSheet<Null>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: _borderRadius,
      ),
      height: 1000.0,
      child: _bottomSheetScreen,
    );
  },
);
```

but it seems like that only affects the contents inside the BottomSheet, and does not customize the BottomSheet itself.

Comment: currently not possible. If you want something custom, use `Navigator` to push a custom modal. There's also a similar issue in github about expanding a bottom sheet : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/497

Comment: Good to know, I'll thumb up that issue. Thanks for the suggestion about using a custom modal with Navigator, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 224):

Default height for **`bottomSheet`** is half the screenSize

If you want your **`bottomSheet` to EXPAND according to your content DYNAMICALLY**

use below code

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
isScrollControlled: true,
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext bc) {
  return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[...]
  )
 }
)
```

This will automatically expand the `bottomSheet` according to content inside.

For **adding a radius on top of `bottomSheet`**  return below code to `bottomSheet'

```
Container(
  child: Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: forDialog ? Color(0xFF737373) : Colors.white,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0))),
      child: yourWidget(),
   ),
)
```

**Complete code meeting both requirements**

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
isScrollControlled: true,
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext bc) {
  return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
          Container(
                 child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: forDialog ? Color(0xFF737373) : Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0))),
                    child: yourWidget(),
                 ),
              )
      ]
   )
 }
)
```

Comment: if there is a ListView in Wrap,it won't be able to scroll.if I replace Wrap to Column,it will be overflow.why?

Comment: @parcool try using `SingleChildScrollView` widget instead of `ListView` widget, that may help you with your query.

Comment: @parcool Actually, you just have to wrap your `ListView` around a `Expanded`, because if the `ListView` is a direct child of `Column`, Flutter will fail to infer its size because `ListView` has a variable size depending on its children as well.

Comment: Great answer, any suggestion for keyboard pushing up the bottom sheet? bottom sheet goes behind keyboard

Comment: To add the radius on top I prefer to add it on shape property of the modal. shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(12))),

Comment: For borderRadius, one could also use shape attr to reduce the number of widgets...

Comment: @Guilherme Matuella The list does not work in the Expanded layout if the widget is in a column that is under the container which has a root view of WrapWidget. Wrap Widget> Container >Column>Expanded>List View

Comment: @RaviParmar I'm pretty sure that when you set the `ListView.shrinkWrap` to `true` or inside an `Expanded` (the latter depending on the parent and siblings), it does allow it to be placed pretty much anywhere. Anyways, I just mentioned this to what @parcool mentioned, it was not a suggestion to this answer whatsoever.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe this is working for me without <dynamic> 
isScrollControlled: true seemed to be what helped

Comment: hi @VickySalunkhe! I'm having an issue with this: in release mode bottomSheet is shown expanded with default height instead of wrapping content, moreover content is covered by a rectangle shape that ignores top border radius styles. Nothing strange happens in debug mode

Comment: @parcool Have you found the answer? or Is there any other approach?  In 2022, still facing same issue,

Answer (score 107):

It's possible this way

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) => Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text("Modal content goes here"),
    ),
  ),
);
```

1. Set `isScrollControlled: true` and `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` for the modal
2. Provide a `Container` with required `height:` as root widget to modal builder
3. Provide `BoxDecoration` with required `borderRadius` for the `Container`

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 26):

You can use a Column Inside a SingleChildScrollView to dynamically change the height of bottom sheet and also it gets scrollable once it exceeds the available max height, make sure the `isScrollControlled` is set to true,
And for the border radius the `shape` property will help you add the borderRadius to the bottomsheet.
here's a [dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/ea1f48220c7f3f0b687a71501a8334a4) for the same

```
  Future<void> _showBottomSheet() async {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List.generate(kBoxes, (index) => _squareBox(index)))),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I find that this works well on the DartPad provided but once implemented in an iOS app, the swipe down to dismiss does not work.

Comment: It works wonders! It's insane  I had been looking for this for ages

Answer (score 26):

No need to wrap anything. Only set:

- `isScrollControlled: true` in `showModalBottomSheet`
- `shrinkWrap: true,` in `ListView`

**Here is the minimal general code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<Widget> show123(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      useRootNavigator: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc) {
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            ListItem(),
            ListItem(),
            ListItem(),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

**You can get inspired by my case** which depends on the number of `AlbumRow` dynamically. If the height reaches the maximum, you can get to the bottom by scrolling.

[image]
[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<Widget> showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      useRootNavigator: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc) {
        return ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9),
          child: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(topLeft: const Radius.circular(25.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(25.0))),
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 45),
                  child: Text(
                    'Choose Album',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                AlbumRow(title: 'For Weekends arta iretnairstnaisetn aistn aisetn'),
                AlbumRow(title: 'Creative'),
                AlbumRow(title: 'Christmas'),
                AlbumRow(title: 'For Weekends arta iretnairstnaisetn aistn aisetn'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Comment: When applying your solution dragging to close the bottom sheet does not work when it has exceeded the specified constraint height

Comment: your example cannot be dragged up, it has a fixed vertical size.

Answer (score 16):

For changing the height of bottomsheet it's better to use the bottomsheet's `constraints` and `isScrollControlled` properties.

Like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75)), // <= this is set to 3/4 of screen size.
  isScrollControlled: true, // <= set to true. setting this without constrains may cause full screen bottomsheet.
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => yourWidget()
);
```

For border radius use the `shape` property:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(45))), // <= set preferable radius.
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => yourWidget()
);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the Code Below

**Note :** If You are using column then use **mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min**

```
// make isScrollControlled : true
// if using column then make - mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
isScrollControlled: true,
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext bc) {
  return YourWidget();
 }
)
```

Comment: Best answer for my use case!

Answer (score 9):

Use **showBottomSheet** instead of showModalBottomSheet

Create global key and a listener

```
final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
VoidCallback _showPersBottomSheetCallBack;
```

Write your method to show the sheet

```
  void _showBottomSheet() {
    setState(() {
      _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = null;
    });

    _scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
      return new Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-100.0,
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("Hi BottomSheet"),
        ),
      );
    })
        .closed
        .whenComplete(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = _showBottomSheet;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

initialize the listener

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = _showBottomSheet;
  }
```

Call the method wherever you required

```
new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: _showPersBottomSheetCallBack,
                  child: new Text("Persistent"),
                ),
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 8):

Based on Vicky's answer, `Wrap` could make alignments miserable. Use instead `Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [...])` in the widget. Implementing that in your example should look like:

```dart
void _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet<Null>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
        mainAxisAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          _bottomSheetScreen
        ]); // defined earlier on
      },
    );
}
```

If you want to control the scrolls with swipes, then try setting `isScrollControlled: true` on the `showModalBottomSheet()`.

Comment: Thanks you solver my problem very helpfull

Answer (score 7):

Lately I found an workaround for this. By setting the `canvasColor` property to `Colors.transparent` in your app's theme, we can make the BottomSheet's overlay disappear.

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'MyApp',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  //...
);
```

Once you set this up, you may use ClipRRect or Decoration with rounded corners.

[image: Bottomsheet with rounded corners]

Comment: this will make all screen background becomes black

Comment: It makes the background of all material element transparent. So you have set a custom color for the material component.

Answer (score 6):

**here is the simplest code working in 2021**

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,  // <-- make bottom sheet resize to content height
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(  // <-- for border radius
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
       return Container() // <-- any widget you want
      });
```

Comment: This automatically makes my bottom sheet go full-screen. I'm using a DefaultTabController & the child is a Column to layout my Tabs & TabBarView and within the TabBarView is another Column to layout my text fields and buttons. Any suggestions? My goal is to make sure this expands to show all text fields and buttons and also raise with the keyboard to make everything visible.

Answer (score 3):

In the above code by @Shyju Madathil you need to add key in scaffold to make it work

```
return new Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the height by setting the height of your main container either by a constant ex : 800 or by using MediaQuery ex :

if i want to show only 2 /3 of the screen

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3)
```

for the radius first you have to set the

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

and then you container color to White or any color you wanted , example :

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(16),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(16))),
  child:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the height by setting `isScrollControlled: true` and wrapping the `BottomSheet` inside `FractionallySizedBox`. It would look something like this:

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    //This
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter state) {
        return FractionallySizedBox(
            //Here specify the high of the BottomSheet
            heightFactor: 0.9,
            child:BottomSheet(
            .
            .
            .
            
            .
            .
            .
      ));
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Wrap(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 40,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Edit Profile",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),`
                              ),
                            ),                           
                          ],
                        );
                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting the 'isScrollable' parameter to "true" makes the bottomsheet go past halfway through the screen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- set `isScrollControlled: true`
- have the child widget sized appropriately

For example, this modal bottom sheet takes up 95% of the screen height:

```
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
// ...
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => SizedBox(
    height: 95.h,
    child: YourWidget(),
  ),
);
```

In the value `95.h`, `h` extension method from the [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package, which allows you to specify values in terms of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use following solution:

```
void _showModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    enableDrag: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        initialChildSize: 0.90, // Initial height as a fraction of screen height
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Content of the bottom sheet
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => Wrap(children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(height: 44, color: Colors.red),
                      Container(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            maxHeight:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text("item $index"),
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: 100),//***Try 3 elements***
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make isScrollControlled : true and use Wrap widget around your page

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return const Wrap(children: [Page()]);
                  },
                );
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution.It can adjust height and has a max height.If the content over max height.It can be scrolled

```
 showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    // elevation: 10,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
      topRight: Radius.circular(12),
    )),
    builder: (context) {
      return ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: List.generate(20, (index) => Text("data$index")),
            )),
      );
    },
  );
```