# How to create a modal bottomsheet with circular corners in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**showModalBottomSheet** does not provide any styling or decorations. I want to create something like the Google Tasks bottomsheet.

[image: google tasks bottomsheet]

Comment: use the showModalBottomSheet shape property which takes ShapeBorder

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This is the modalBottomSheet function needed.

```
    void _modalBottomSheetMenu(){
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (builder){
              return new Container(
                height: 350.0,
                color: Colors.transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373), 
                           //so you don't have to change MaterialApp canvasColor
                child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                    )),
              );
            }
        );
      }
```

Also the most important part of this working properly is, in MaterialApp set canvasColor to transparent like the one shown below.

```
return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Tasks',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      home: new TasksHomePage(),
    );
  }
```

I have tested the code and it works fine as I was also making a clone of the Google Tasks app which will be opensourced in my [github](https://github.com/thelazyindian).

Comment: Changing global `canvasColor` for a bottomSheet round corner is not a good tradeoff. use `Theme` wrapper instead. Also if you widgets inside the bottom sheet is theme depended then use `data: yourTheme().copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent)` just to apply canvas color only to its child. Best option would be the Updated one.

Comment: Doing this will change canvas color for all the app, which means that, for example, the 'Select/Copy/Paste' native tooltip will have a transparent background color instead of the default white. I think this should be the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62457068/7691350

Comment: Theme wrapper with canvasColor not worked. So I used `bottomSheetTheme:
            BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent)` in MaterialApp theme.

Comment: I think using bottomSheetTheme as @temirbek's answer is the best way in this case.

Answer (score 317):

### UPDATED ON 2019-08-05

You can now do it using the default `showModalBottomSheet` method that now supports adding a `ShapeBorder` and also `backgroundColor`!

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0)),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  ...
);
```

### --

Instead of overriding the entire theme of the app (which caused problems in various parts of my app) as suggested by other answers, I decided to take a look at the implementation for `showModalBottomSheet` and find the problem myself. Turns out that all that was needed was wrapping the main code for the modal in a `Theme` widget that contains the `canvasColor: Colors.transparent` trick. I also made it easier to customize the radius and also the color of the modal itself.

You can use either the [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rounded_modal) on pub or a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gildaswise/5d1b7bee327a9dd6cc5bcd1bbc72316a) containing the same code. Don't forget to import the proper package/file.

```dart
showRoundedModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    radius: 20.0,  // This is the default
    color: Colors.white,  // Also default
    builder: (context) => ???,
);
```

Comment: +1.
For me it was not sufficient to wrap only the button which contained the method for showing the modal bar. But wrapping the Scaffold which contained the screen with such a Theme worked.

`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      // We need this theme override so that the corners of the bottom sheet modal can be rounded
      data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: Scaffold(
....`

Comment: For me I also needed to add `clipBehaviour: Clip.hardEdge` to make to corners round

Answer (score 139):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
context:context
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Better answer Thanks.

Comment: this should be accepted answer as it doens't require setting canvas color globally. it's more concise

Comment: `Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer` makes it so that if the content of the modal sheet is scrollable, the scrollable content will also be clipped to the modal's border radius if anyone was wondering.

Comment: clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias should be preferred, since Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer is very slow.

Comment: Only this one worked for me

Comment: clipBehavior was the trick!!!

Answer (score 44):

I think the best way to do a rounded-corner modal is to use a `RoundedRectangleBorder` with a vertical `BorderRadius`, setting only its `top` property:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return your layout
        });
```

Using separate radii for top left and top right is a bit more verbose and error-prone.

Answer (score 23):

i have this code and work well for me. please check it and let me know you'r opinion.

```
showBottomSheet(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              top: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Container(
                height: 250,

                child: new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0))),
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                    )),
              ))
```

Answer (score 19):

You can now simply set the `shape` argument.
Example:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
  ),
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => MyBottomSheet(),
);
```

Answer (score 13):

Set the shape to **RoundedRectangleBorder** should work, but sometimes the content overflows making round corners missing, when this happens **set clipBehavior to Clip.antiAlias** to resolve.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: colorOnPrimary,
    // set this when inner content overflows, making RoundedRectangleBorder not working as expected
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    // set shape to make top corners rounded
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(16), 
            topRight: Radius.circular(16),
        ),
    ),
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(),
        );
    },
)
```

Answer (score 12):

one way is by using`showModalBottomSheet` `shape` property,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context:context
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Putting together all the answers before, I could achieve the best result possible (in my opinion) for this.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[     
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                title: Text('Send email'),
                onTap: () {
                  print('Send email');
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                title: Text('Call phone'),
                 onTap: () {
                    print('Call phone');
                  },
               ),                  
            ],
          );
        });
```

Comment: this isn't working. please confirm before replying

Answer (score 6):

You can add a `RoundedRectangleBorder` widget inside the `showModalBottomSheet`:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10.0)
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
     context: context,
     builder: (ctx) {
      return Container( 
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green, // or some other color
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0)
       ) 
     );
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

for persistent bottom sheet, add the following code in the material app widget's theme property

```
ThemeData(          
          bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give borderRadius in decoration container also.

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (builder){
                  return  Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
                                topRight: const Radius.circular(15.0))),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                        ),
                  );
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context:context
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
)
```

It will be much better to use Clip.hardEdge. As it is faster than other clipping modes but slower than [none].

Answer (score 1):

you can now do it with the showModelBottomSheet() widget parameter shape

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
           shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topLeft: 
                      Radius.circular(24),topRight:Radius.circular(24) ),),
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `showModalBottomSheet`

> shape:

property which takes `ShapeBorder`
as shown below

```
 shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just answered a related question

You can **add corners to your `bottomSheet`** and **expand your `bottomSheet` according to content** present inside it (not restricted to half size of screen)

check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59541927/9236994)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59541927/9236994