# having hard time implementing rounded edge modal bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

hi guys im trying to implement rounded corner modalbottomsheet in flutter , this is my code

```
void _showModalSheet(){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return  ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), topRight:Radius.circular(20.0))

            ,child: Container(
              height: 350.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFF01579B),

              ),

              child : new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                          height: 80.0,
                          width: 100.0,

                          child: new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Icon(Icons.directions_car, size: 30.0,color: Colors.white,),
                              new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                              new Text('Emergency', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            color : Color(0XFF82B1FF),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: ()=> print("hello")
                      ),

                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                          height: 80.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: new Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Icon(Icons.person, size: 30.0,color: Colors.white,),
                                new SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                new Text('Security issue', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            color : Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: ()=> print("hello")
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                          height: 80.0,
                          width: 100.0,

                          child: new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Icon(Icons.local_car_wash, size: 30.0,color: Colors.white,),
                              new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                              new Text('Emergency', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            color : Color(0XFFBF360C),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: ()=> print("hello")
                      ),

                    ],
                  )
                  ,  new SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(13.0, 5.0,10.0,5.0),
                    child: new Text("Ride sharing :", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18.0 , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
                  ),
                  new SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 100.0,

                            child: Center(
                              child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Report",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  new SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                  new Text("Report incidence",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                              color : Colors.white,
                            )
                        ),
                          onTap: ()=> print("hello")
                      ),

                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 100.0,

                            child: Center(
                              child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Announce",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  new SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                  new Text("Announcement",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                              color :Color(0XFF8BC34A),
                            )
                        ),
                        onTap: ()=> print("hello"),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: new Container(
                            height: 80.0,
                            width: 100.0,

                            child: Center(
                              child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text("Security tips ",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13.0),),
                                  new SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                  new Text("Tips",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                              color: Color(0XFF1A237E),
                            )
                        ),
                          onTap: ()=> print("hello")
                      ),

                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
          ),
          );

        }
    );
  }
```

This is what I got with the code:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376200/how-to-create-a-modal-bottomsheet-with-circular-corners-in-flutter). The accepted answer recommends that you should set the canvasColor of your MaterialApp Widget to transparent.

```
return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      canvasColor: Colors.transparent, // setting canvasColor to transparent
    ),
    home: YourHomePage(), // your home page
  );
```

Comment: So will that change the coloyr of my modalbottomdheet to blue?

Comment: Your modalbottomsheet will always remain in color blue. We only need to set your MaterialApp's canvasColor to transparent so that the white colored canvas on your topLeft and topRight will become transparent.

Comment: not work.......

Answer (score 2):

:)

It's a little bit late but I hope help to someone with your same problem. The only thing you need to do if you want add rounded corners is add "**backgroundColor: Colors.transparent**" on your **showModalBottomSheet** to delete white background:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (context){
     return ...
});
```

Comment: not work as well..